# Realm object in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion, realm

**Question**
How can I create an array of objects containing Realm objects?

**Code**

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let data: [A] = realm.objects(A)
```

**Error**

*Cannot invoke 'objects' with an argument list of type '(Object.type)'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create an array of objects containing Realm objects?

From your code sample, I'll further assume that you want to make an array from a Realm `Results`, not just "standalone" Realm objects.

Since `Results` conforms to `SequenceType`, you can use `SequenceType.map()` to convert it into an array:

```
let arrayFromResults = results.map({ $0 })
```

Note, however, that this is almost always the wrong pattern to use.

From [your tweet](https://twitter.com/thecodeman7/status/676536703755137024) on the same topic, a preferable way to do this would be to encode what you want to display on screen as a Realm query:

```
self.results = realm.objects(A).filter("poppedOff == NO")
```

And "popping off" an object (whatever that means) would update the `poppedOff` property of that object.

Since Realm `Results` are auto-updating, this won't risk getting out of sync with the contents of the Realm, unlike the array conversion approach, which would have to be updated on every Realm change notification.

Comment: you were right. I have edited the question to what I need.